# (PowerShellForGitHub) PowerShell Set-GitHubContent messes up the encoding of the csproj file

Tags: powershell, github

Greeting all,
I wonder if someone encountered similar issue or knows the solution to that problem:
I am using PS module PowerShellForGitHub to perform some work in my github repositories.
One of actions is to make changes to the net standard project file.
For that the function Set-GitHubContent is used.
After I push up the changes the project file becomes unreadable by VisualStudio with the error

*error  : The project file could not be loaded. Name cannot begin with the '.' character, hexadecimal value 0x00. Line 1, position 2.*

Clearly the encoding issue as the file is opened fine by notepad and looks good.
I cant figure out how the issue is happening.
I tried a very simple code

```
$test=@'
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
    <Configurations>Debug;Release;AllInOne</Configurations>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
'@
Set-GitHubContent -OwnerName 'aa' -RepositoryName "RepName" -Path "ProjectFile.csproj" -CommitMessage "any"  -Content  "$test" -BranchName "main"
```

and even that code messes up the project file.
Any ideas what is going on?
Thanks,
Arbus

Comment: If this is your real code, the `'@` is placed wrong. It should be at the very beginning of the line; not x spaces further down.

Comment: it was due to the editing, corrected it, thanks